# Put and idempotent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http, rest

If you model contains a filed which are called "created" and "updated"

When you use PUT to update content to this record..

1. Should created be set to the time of data creation or modification? Since PUT is idempotent, so it should not rely on previous value
2. Since updated is always modified when you issue the request, so it violated the principle of idempotent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should created be set to the time of data creation or modification? Since PUT is idempotent, so it should not rely on previous value.

I don't really understand what you're asking here. There's no reason `created_at` would be set to the modification time, since they are two distinct concepts.

> Since updated is always modified when you issue the request, so it violated the principle of idempotent?

Your assumption that `updated_at` is always modified isn't true (at least not in Rails, nor should it be anywhere else). If you do an identical `PUT` multiple times, idempotence is not violated since these subsequent requests don't modify any of the attributes, and thus the `updated_at` time is *not* changed.

There is an interesting [post on the Rails blog about `PUT` & `PATCH`](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) that adds a lot more to this. The way I see it, the user should never send `created_at` or `updated_at` with their request (since the server should probably usually ignore them and set them itself), though it is indeed questionable if this violates the idea that a `PUT` should send the entire object. However, if that idea is ignored (as it often is in Rails, and perhaps elsewhere), then `PUT` is indeed idempotent.

Comment: Re:" There's no reason created_at ...", sure, but just want to align with the meaning of "idempotent"

Comment: Howard's point is that, under the HTTP spec, there shouldn't be any observable difference between PUT creating or modifying a resource. The resource you end up with is supposed to be identical either way, and the created_at field doesn't jibe with this.

Comment: @Chuck How so? When would, after the `PUT` request has completed, the object ever have a different `created_at`?

Answer (score 0):

With put you don't alter created_at you alter modified_at or whatever it's called. Created_at is only set upon creation. BTW, both, post and put can be used to create and update values.